# Marriage In Jannah with someone else

Tags: nikah, jannah, husband-wife, day-of-judgement, love

What happens if a Muslim wife serves her husband and pleases him but doesn't want to be with him in Jannah and marry with someone else, is she given a choice ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wishing husband to be only mine in Jannah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23446/wishing-husband-to-be-only-mine-in-jannah)

Answer (score 2):

Our appearances in Jannah will be way more beautiful and amazing and just remember in Jannah we will be satisfied and happy from our Lord and our Lord will be happy from us.

But such thinking about a person who is not your spouse in this world can end up in sins or other troubles in this life, so it is advised to shed off any such thoughts and live with *sabar* and *shukar* in this life with the spouse you are given.

Answer (score 0):

You will have whatever you ask for in Jannah.. It is in the Quran. IN SHAA ALLAH if you still desire that man you like if you reach Jannah you will have him. Don't listen to anyone who says you won't have him. If you are fulfilling your Islamic duties in Dunya and if ALLAH (SWT) grants you Jannah then you will get WHATEVER you want IN SHAA ALLAH